# count unique values in each row data table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table like

```
    col1     col2     col3    col4
1:    a        a        a       2
2:    b        b        a       4.4
3:    w        w        s       6.3
```

I want to get something like below without running a for loop.

```
    col1     col2     col3    col4   count
1:     a        a        a        2      1
2:     b        b        a        4.4    2
3:     w        w        s        6.3    2
```

I am counting unique values of col1, col2, col3 in each row and storing in count column. How do I do this in 1 line?

Comment: How about applying `length(unique())` to a transposed version of the matrix minus col4?

Comment: this is one round about way of doing it, but then it involves converting data table to a matrix and then converting back to a data table. I am sure there must be some way of doing it as data table only. But not able to figure out that.

Answer (score 7):

This might be of use:

#### data.frame solution

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text='   col1     col2     col3    col4
1    a        a        a       2
2    b        b        a       4.4
3    w        w        s       6.3')

#one line using apply    
df$count <- apply(df[1:3], 1, function(x) {length(unique(x))})
```

Output:

```
> df
  col1 col2 col3 col4 count
1    a    a    a  2.0     1
2    b    b    a  4.4     2
3    w    w    s  6.3     2
```

#### data.table solution

It will be a bit trickier to use the `data.table` syntax in this example.

First I create an id column by which to group_by:

```
#convert original df to data.table
df2 <- as.data.table(df)
df2[, id := 1:nrow(df2) ]
```

and then I use my self-made luna function to calculate the length of the unique elements:

```
luna <- function(x)   length(unique(unlist(strsplit(x,''))))
df2[, count := luna(paste0(col1, col2, col3)), by=id ]
```

Output:

```
> df2
   col1 col2 col3 col4 id count
1:    a    a    a  2.0  1     1
2:    b    b    a  4.4  2     2
3:    w    w    s  6.3  3     2
```

Or as @Tensibai mentions in the comments, this is much faster:

```
df2 <- as.data.table(df)
df2[, id := 1:nrow(df2) ]
luna <- function(x)   length(unique(x))

df2[, count2 := luna(c(col1, col2, col3)), by=id ]

> df2
   col1 col2 col3 col4 id count2
1:    a    a    a  2.0  1      1
2:    b    b    a  4.4  2      2
3:    w    w    s  6.3  3      2
```

And if we combine @Frank's and @Tensibai 's comments this should be the fastest **(data.table 1.9.5+)**:

```
df2 <- as.data.table(df)
df2[, id := 1:nrow(df2) ]

#not run
#works only in data.table >= 1.9.5
df2[, count2 := uniqueN(c(col1, col2, col3)), by=id ]
#not run
```

Comment: probably better to call `col1`...`col3` instead of `1:3`.

Comment: Can you please modify your answer to the syntax of a data.table?

Comment: My data is huge, so "$" method will take too long, that is why I have asked for a data.table syntax?

Comment: Fwiw, `uniqueN(x)` is a fast shortcut to `length(unique(x))` available in 1.9.5 (and could sub into your `luna`).

Comment: @Frank Oh wow! I didn't know of this function. I am using 1.9.4 at the moment. I will update data.table and retry it. I ll update the answer then. Thanks.

Comment: Ok cool. Heads up: it's not on CRAN yet, so you'll need to follow these instructions: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation

Comment: I would remove the `unlist(strplit())` and replace `paste0()` by `c()`, do I miss something about this ?

Comment: @Tensibai Thanks for this. Yeah it is much better. I ll update the answer. Thanks. I was checking/testing lots of things before I made it work.

Comment: I think it'd be okay to just show Tensibai's approach (and not the paste one). A couple more minor things: you can use `id := .I`; and, instead of enumerating columns, `df2[, count2 := luna(c(.SD)), by=id, .SDcols = col1:col3 ]` (not sure if that only works in 1.9.5). Also, might be good to add a caveat about uniqueN requiring v 1.9.5+ of the package, since it's not on CRAN yet.

Comment: @Frank I didn't want to use .SD on purpose as it takes a long time to run based on a report I read from the author. I wanted a solution using just by. And using `.I` is pretty much the same as `1:nrow(df2)` although  I agree it is more compact to use `.I` (not sure about speed). I mention about `uniqueN` requiring data.table `1.9.5+` in a comment above the code.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
dt <- CJ(1:5,1:3,1:4,1:2)
dt[, cnt:=apply(dt, 1, function(r) length(unique(r)))]
```

or if you only want to keep the rows with unique entries, you can try

```
dt <- CJ(1:5,1:3,1:4,1:2)
dt[apply(dt, 1, function(r) length(unique(r))==ncol(dt))]
```